# Trace manipulation in finding the matrix element squared

Tags: dirac-matrices, trace

Here's the $s$-channel of the scalar-fermion scattering given that $L_{int} = -g\phi\bar\psi\psi$:

[image]

And I found the matrix element of this channel is

[image]

Then to find $\sum_{s,s'}|\tilde M_1|^2$:

[image]

I was told that the trace term could be simplified to the bottom line of result, but I'm stuck on how to get there.

Multiplying those four terms inside the brace, we could get something like:

$$
\text{Tr}({{\not} p'{\not} k'{\not} p{\not} k }+m {\not} k'{\not} p'{\not} k' + 2m {\not} p'{\not} p{\not} k' + ...+ 4m^4  ).
$$

Edit: After taking the trace, we obtain

$$
4(p'\cdot k'k'\cdot p-p'\cdot pk'\cdot k'+p\cdot 'k'k'\cdot p) +8m^2pk'+4m^2k'k'+8m^2p'k'+8m^3k'p+16m^2p'p+8m^2p'k'+16m^4
$$
I'm stuck on how to further simplify this to get the desired result. For example, the final result doesn't include the $m^3$ term, so should $k'p = 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: In an expression like $\not p+m$, do you understand what matrix is implicitly multiplying the $m$? You can’t just add a number to a matrix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities

Comment: Why didn’t you ask about the terms with one and two slashes?

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks for the comment! The implicit matrix is $I_4$, right? For two slashes terms, I wanted to use $\text{Tr}( {\not} p{\not} q) = 4pq$. I'm also not quite sure how to deal with the one slash term

Comment: Yes, $I_4$. For any odd number of slashes, see either https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Feynman_slash_notation or the previous link I provided.

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks, that's really helpful, they should vanish, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.